# E / Z Isomers GC peaks for identification; Would GC-MS help?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, isomers, identification

Does a GC analysis typically seperate E / Z isomers? I'm reading a paper that confirms that the product it synthesized was indeed the (E,E) isomer by coinjecting a standard sample on the GC.

My question is, had they actually made an (Z,Z) or (E,Z) or (Z,E) would a typical GC show two different peaks?

In other words, for isomer verification of this nature is a GC co-injection a sufficient control? Or would it be more prudent to co-inject standard samples of the other samples too in other runs to demonstrate that those indeed elute differently?

The paper also claims they have verified the compound as a (E,E) by a GC-MS analysis but would (E,E) (E,Z) etc. show different patterns on a GC-MS?

[image]

Comment: These isomers would be significantly different. I don't think the diphosphate would be seen by GC, but the alcohols should separate. In the past week, I've seen several chromatograms where [geraniol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geraniol) and [nerol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerol) separated just fine.